# How to disable all Fragments from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am making tabs using FragmentActivity and Fragments in my android app. My FragmentActivity  has 5 fragments. I want to disable all fragments when i click a button in my fragment 1. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable (`yourTabsView.setEnable(false);`) your tab controllers in FragmentActivity.

For this you should change(if its not like this) your activity layout structure :

- Main Layout

  - Tabs Layout
  - Fragments Layout

Comment: How can i disable main main tab view from my fragment?

Comment: I am disabling my FragmentTabHost in FragmentActivity. And isEnabled() is returning false but i still can touch the tabs. Any idea why are they not disabled?